# Loading chapter data in VLC from external file for any video format

Tags: ffmpeg, video, vlc-media-player, chapters

I have a number of video files (in various formats: mp4, webm, mkv, etc.) and I'd like to add chapter information to them (similar to how Youtube shows links into parts of videos).

I'm not terribly familiar with video formats and I know of some tools that can encode chapter information into particular video formats but I'd like to avoid modifying the video files, if possible. I'd also like to add chapters to all the video formats I have, even if the format itself may not support this.

Can I define chapter information in a text file, something like this:

```
CHAPTER01=00:00:00.000
CHAPTER01NAME=Title
CHAPTER02=00:01:12.000
CHAPTER02NAME=The Beginning
...
```

and then have VLC load this file along with the video? (Similar to how it can load subtitles from external files.)

Answer (score 1):

No, VLC doesn't have such a capability as of today.

Your best bet is converting to a format that support chapters and embedding them there.

You could also try mpv and its [`--chapters-file`](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-chapters-file) option, but it's not too well documented as to what's accepted as a format. There's [this script](https://github.com/mar04/chapters_for_mpv) which claims to be able to create text files for media files while watching in mpv and then automatically load them.